# If the unique pointer constructor is explicit why is it possible to assign it to make_unique<T>()?

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion, unique-ptr

I understand that because of the `explicit` keyword in the constructor of `unique_ptr` the following will throw an error:

`std::unique_ptr<int> p = new int()`

That is because we are relying on implicit conversion. To make it work we would need to explicitly call the constructor as follows:

`std::unique_ptr<int> p(new int())`

But I am confused why does the following work:

`std::unique_ptr<int> p = std::make_unique<int>();`

We are not calling the constructor explicitly. Isn't this also a type of implicit conversion?

Comment: This is invoking the move constructor (at most, today it's elided), not the default constructor. Different c'tors can differ in their explicit specifier.

Comment: Also not every `unique_ptr` constructor is explicit. The constructor that takes ownership of a raw pointer is explicit, but the move constructor is not.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica, and that's an answer!

Comment: _We are not calling the constructor explicitly._ We are not, but `std::make_unique` does is for us. _Isn't this also a type of implicit conversion?_ It is, but it is resolved by the move constructor, which is not explicit.